# PostgreSQL 9.2.4 - Desire to Change the Localhost Server Password in Mavericks & Databases

Tags: macos, postgresql, osx-mavericks, postgresql-9.2

Currently PostgreSQL 9.2.4 is provided in OSX Mavericks.  I have used the provided PostgreSQL since running Lion Server.  When I started using it I was using a password that I now realize is not very secure.

I am having trouble finding the right command to do this.  The user/role (I supposed) that is provided is _postgres.  This is the password I would like to change.  I attempted the command below but honestly I'm not sure what it is supposed to do.  I thought that this would allow me to access the role/user.

```
psql -U _postgres -h localhost -W
```

Here is what happened when I attempted to execute this command.

```
xxxx:~ xxxx$ psql -U _postgres -h localhost -W
Password for user _postgres: 
psql: FATAL:  database "_postgres" does not exist
```

_postgres is the user for all my databases.  I would like to change the password for _postgres.  I'm not sure since the databases were created by _postgres that once I change that password if the password will work for the databases or if I will have to change the database passwords also.

All the solutions dealing with this reference directories that I do not have in Mavericks.  When I used Lion and Mountain Lion I was able to go to the psql directory and find postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf.  I do a search on those files and do not find them.

Sidebar: I currently use PgAdmin3 for basic database maintenance.  The Mac version of the software does not have an option for changing passwords that I can find.  If there is another GUI software package that is more user friendly for accessing the provided PostgreSQL I would definitely like to try it.  Every solution that suggests Homebrew is in the context of installing another version of PostgreSQL which is not what I want to do.

I need the correct terminal command(s) to do this or help on where to go to get the solution that will work with OS X Mavericks.  The PostgreSQL documentation is a bit overwhelming and was not clear as to where to go and what to do regarding this.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE 4/5 6:03 pm CDT**

Here are the contents in /Library/Server/PostgreSQL/Data/pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     _postgres                                trust
#host    replication     _postgres        127.0.0.1/32            trust
#host    replication     _postgres        ::1/128                 trust
```

Comment: `psql -U _postgres -h localhost -W -d postgres` (if you omit the databasename, pg assumes a database with the username as its name. Which does not exist in your case)

Comment: Thanks so much.  I'm in the terminal.  Would I do ALTER USER _postgres WITH PASSWORD '<newpassword>'; to change it?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/sql-alteruser.html `ALTER USER _postgres password 'newpassword'` the `WITH` is a syntactic noise word.

Comment: I executed the command and changed the password.  However when I go into pgadmin3 I can put the old password in and access my databases.  I also notice that I have no problems accessing the databases in my Ruby on Rails applications that have the original password in the database.yml file.  I guess I have a bigger problem that I realize.  I need to get my PostgreSQL database secure.  It appears that my so-called passwords are meaningless.

Comment: Did you add a semicolon to the statement : `ALTER USER _postgres password 'newpassword';` and did it echo `ALTER ROLE/USER` ?

Comment: _I do a search on those files and do not find them_: use the SQL commands `show hba_file;` and `show config_file;` when logged inside the `psql` interpreter. Then review `pg_hba.conf` to check what authentication methods are assigned to connections from localhost.

Comment: wildplasser I did the command again to make sure that I had the semicolon. The echo said ALTER ROLE.  I exited the command and entered it again.  When I typed the original password it let me into the terminal even though I believe it should have rejected the password since it was supposedly changed.

Comment: Daniel, I added what was in pg_hba.conf to my question.  I wonder if I need to uncomment out some of the statements regarding _postgres.

Comment: `host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust` need I say more?

Comment: wildplasser, this gives me a starting point.  I will need to change your suggestion somehow where I can require a password when doing maintenance but allow me to stop and start postgres. If I change this from trust to md5 or password I cannot restart postgres after modifying the configuration. I can if I leave the method as trust which is not what I want.  I want to require a password for user _postgres for any action I want to take.  I will look at the pg_hba.conf documentation to see if I can do this.  I have reviewed a few other posts about this but none of them give a solution that worked.