# Rails 4 - Desire To Set PostgreSQL Password & Access Database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql, postgresql-9.2, rails-postgresql

I added the following question in April 2014 hoping to set up a password for PostgreSQL but never found a workable solution.  I am using a Mac Mini Server running the latest version of Mavericks with PostgreSQL 9.2.8.

[PostgreSQL 9.2.4 - Desire to Change the Localhost Server Password in Mavericks & Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882280/postgresql-9-2-4-desire-to-change-the-localhost-server-password-in-mavericks)

When I created the database I did not realize that I never set a password for it.  I have one that I want to use.  However as you can see in the posted question everything I tried either locked me out of PostgreSQL where I could not start or stop it or the password I attempted to set was not recognized.  pgAdmin does not allow me to set the password.  The changes I attempted in  /Library/Server/PostgreSQL/Data/pg_hba.conf did not work.  I cannot find a .pgpass file anywhere nor I did not create one.

When I do the command below and hit return at the password prompt I'm able to get into the terminal.

```
psql -U _postgres -h localhost -W -d postgres
```

I have searched again trying to find a solution but have not found one that I could try that was not like the solutions suggested in my original question.  I want to access my database with a password in my Rails applications and using the psql terminal or pgAdmin.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE 8/9/2014 3:25 pm Central

Here are my original statements in my `pg_hba.conf` file:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Changed to the following:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Got the following error when trying to restart.  The same thing happened using password instead of md5.

```
sudo serveradmin start postgres

postgres:error = "CANNOT_START_SERVICE_TIMEOUT_ERR"
```

When I changed the md5/password back to trust I was able to start postgres again.  I did not add the statements I had in my question I asked in April.

Comment: According to your other question, password checking is disabled in `pg_hba.conf` for all localhost connections. When you enable it, you say then: _I cannot restart postgres_. This is not normal and is the part that should get fixed. It would help to describe that part in terms of actual attempted commands and error messages.

Comment: Also note that a password is asked in your command above because of the `-W` option to psql. That option doesn't help with your case, just leave it out.

Comment: @DanielVérité, I have added the statements that I currently have in my pg_hba.conf file with the problems I had starting postgres.  I have tried again to search for a simple step by step process on how to set this file up where I can require a password when accessing the database in the terminal or anywhere the database is accessed, including my Rails applications.  Unfortunately what I have added in the description and other things I have tried have caused me not to be able to start postgres.  The only setting working is trust which I don't want.  If you need more information let me know.

Comment: Googling `CANNOT_START_SERVICE_TIMEOUT_ERR` indicates this  error is specific to OSX server. In: https://discussions.apple.com/message/22217729 your exact problem is brought up and if I understand correctly they say this error can be ignored, it's not really an error in the sense that postgres actually starts.